# Examples of Loopback Applications for Testing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

I think it's useful to test relations and there's virtually no documentation or standard way of approaching testing in loopback. I'm wondering if there's an example applications of any size that go into testing.

Is there a set of tools that is recommended?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The repo `loopback-example-relations` might be useful:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-relations

It sets up some example models that contain all relations between them.

You can follow doc http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Tutorial-model-relations.html to see how to use them.
And also fork the repo to try those examples.